# Head First C# - Chapter 1 propertytoanimate not working

Tags: c#

I am currently running throught this course Head First `C#` and I got stuck at the end of a first lesson where last error remains and I have no idea how to fix it please could some of you help?

thank you, really appreciate it

[image]

This is the problematic code... property to animate is at the end of it
     Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);

```
    using System;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;



    namespace Save_The_Human
    {   
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        private double To;

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddEnemy();
        }
        private void AddEnemy()
        {
            ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
            enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100),
                random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), "(Canvas.Top)");
            playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
        }

        private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            {
                var From = from;
                To = to;
                var Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)));
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe the problem cannot be explained by just looking into the code you have shared. There might be an issue in the `SetTarget` or `SetTargetProperty` methods.

Comment: you get the error at compiletime or ? the code is allmost the same as the example here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br210503 - the only difference I can see is that in the example the line with SetTarget goes after the line with SetTargetProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a breaking change in some version of .NET or something like that.

You can fix it by replacing the declaration of `AnimateEnemy` method and calls to it:

```
...
AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 25, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 25), random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 25), new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
...
private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, PropertyPath propertyToAnimate)
...
```